# An exercise from Rotman's advanced modern algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I have been stuck in an exercise from Rotman's advanced modern algebra for a while,which is stated below:

> Let $K/k$ be a field extension. If $A \subseteq K$ and $u \in k(A)$, prove that there are $a_1,...,a_n \in A$ with $u \in k(a_1,...,a_n)$.

I have no idea how to deal with it, since $K/k$ may be algebraic or not, so is $k(A)$.

Can anyone give a complete proof or just a hint? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Is $A$ just a subset of $K$? If so, how  do you define $k(A)$?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks!Yeah,I should have mentioned that A is merely a subset of K and k(A) is the smallest field containing A,i.e.,obtained by adjoining A into k.

Comment: Thus you only have to show  that the set of all such $u$s, is a field, since anyway, it's obvious that $k(A)$, as you define it, contains them.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry,but I'm still wondering how do we find a1,...,an∈A for a given u∈k(A)?

Comment: @Bernard Clearly,the case that A is finite is simple,but what if A is infinite?That's why I am confused.

Comment: But when you consider a specific element in $k(A)$, it involves only a finite number of element of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Write $\; A=\bigcup\limits_{\substack{B\text{ finite}}\\B\,\subset\, A}B$ and order the finite subsets  of $A$ by inclusion.  The set of finite subsets of $A$ is directed.

Show that if $B, C$ are finite such that $B\subset C$, there corresponds an inclusion morphism $\;i:k(B)\hookrightarrow k(C)$, and that if $B\subset C\subset D$, then the composition $k(B)\hookrightarrow  k(C)\hookrightarrow  k(D)$ is the same as $k(B)\hookrightarrow  k(D)$ (resulting from the inclusion $B\subset D$).

This proves that $k(A)$ is the `direct limit` of the `inductive system` of fields $\;\bigl(k(B),i\bigr)_{\substack{B\text{ finite}}\\B\,\subset\, A}$.

Any element in the direct limit is the image of an element in some $k(B)$, thus proving the initial assertion.

Comment: Ummm...Seems like the knowledge it requires exceeds the range of the current chapter,but anyway,thanks a lot!

Comment: It is expressed more or less in the language of categories, but  be aware that, in the present case, the direct limit is just the union (indexed by the set of finite subsets of $A$).

Comment: Get it,thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

u is a finite sum de element of k and A with coeficients in k then you only need to attach those elemtens of A that belong in that sum.

Comment: $u$ is a rational function over $k$ of elements of $A$.